# css - create a block element whose width is only as large as the text contained within

Tags: css

I have this fiddle where there is a rollover style applied to a paragraph - but I want that paragraph to only be as wide as the text contained within (not the entire width of the containing element). If I do display:inline-block it brings each menu option up to the same line but sets the width of each item appropriately. How do I combine both (options on separate lines, but only as wide as the text contained inside)?

http://jsfiddle.net/heaversm/wxqeW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a span and set the hover state to the span

Fiddle ------> [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wxqeW/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also have the background color change when you hover the entire `<p>` Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wxqeW/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a

```
width: auto;
```

to the css. Also check that the divs are not floating.